# How to make local APNS push notifications silent?

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native

Working off this guide I have local push notifications working perfectly:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html

However I don't want to send a local push notification with sound if the user's time is at night as that could get annoying real fast as a game is not that important.

How do I make the local push notification silent?

Currently, it is working and playing a sound. If I leave off soundName it plays the default sound, if I set it to default it plays the default sound, and if I make it an empty string it plays a sound. The above linked guide isn't really clear on what the options are other than to say soundName is optional.

```
PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
  alertBody: "Hello From app",
  applicationIconBadgeNumber: 1,
  fireDate:  waitingUntil.getTime(),
  soundName: ''
})
```

Comment: When you said 'and if I make it an empty string it plays a sound' is that still playing the default sound?

Comment: Yes, it was the default sound. Taking a look at your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to reproduce the issue that you are having and I have created a sample app that you can make fire two notifications. One of the notifications does not play a sound and sets the app's badge, the other one plays a sound and clears the badge. Maybe something in there can help you figure out what is going wrong.

https://github.com/AidenMontgomery/react-native-sample

The checked in version of the code is configured to run on a device, as I could not get any sounds to play at all on the simulator.

Comment: Thank you for an example! I'd give more than 1 vote if I could. Not sure what I was seeing the other night as it works as expected today. It could be that I was on the simulator or something the other night. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. I am sure that notifications are something that I will need to do on one of the apps I am working on sometime soon, so it was good to do some research into it.